# Saving video on server with flash, php and RED5

Tags: php, flash, red5

I have a PHP website and I want my visitors (logged in users) to record their webcam and save video on server. I wrote the streaming code and it works well between Flash and RED5. The only question is, by what name should I save the video?

One possible approach is when the PHP page loads, I output logged in user's username and pass it into Flash and Flash passes it to RED5 server and then RED5 server creates a video by that username. My users will be only having 1 video/account so this will work well.

Is there any better approach than this one? Is there any downside to what I have planned?

Comment: I would say use a token and a lookup table in your database vut since its just one video you can store the video url straight into the users table, the file name wont matter. you could add another column in the users table for the video title.